# How to change column name in VIEW table?

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl, sql-view, create-view

How to change column name in SQL?
I have tried the following but giving a syntax error.

```sql
create view cView as select * from College;
alter table cView
rename cName to collegeName,
rename enrollment to seats;
```

Comment: Alter the view with new names. You can not rename column name of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly rename columns in a view, but you can recreate it with the new names you want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE cView AS
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       cName AS collageName,
       enrollment AS seat,
       someOtherColumn
       -- etc...
FROM   myTable
```